# Can't get form class object in template view

Tags: python, django

I want to get the form object from self.Form

This is my form

```
class ActionLogSearchForm(forms.Form):
    key_words = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

and I set form as form_class, however I can't fetch the form data in `view`

```
class ActionLogListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListSearchView):
    template_name = "message_logs/action_log.html"
    form_class = ActionLogSearchForm
    def get_queryset(self):
        res = []        
        form = self.form ## somehow form is None
        print(form.cleaned_data) # error occurs here. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

I think this is the simplest set, but how can I make it work?

Comment: Is this Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

class ActionLogSearchForm(forms.Form):
    key_words = forms.CharField(required=False)

class ActionLogListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListSearchView, request):
    form_class = ActionLogSearchForm
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        res = []        
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.form(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'message_logs/action_log.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You have missed `)` in `self.form(request.POST)`. And if you don't give `return render...` at the end, and simple give `template_name`, then also it will work, as already given by OP.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works well for me . I found another solution if I set `model = DummyModel` somehow. self.form returns the object. I am not sure why.

Comment: @whitebear what problem do you exactly facing right now?

Comment: No problem, you solve my problem already. I have checked now.